# Is it safe to delete every pointer in C++ as a pointer to an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, delete-operator

Is it safe to delete every pointer in C++ as a pointer to an array?

Will it be fine for me if I will always write `delete [] ptr` with no regard what `ptr` actually is - whether it is a pointer to a single object or an array of objects?

Comment: You might just as well ask "Q: if I allocate an object with 'malloc()', can release it with 'delete'?"  A: NO!  Q: Why would you even ask such a question?  Just to be arbitrary... or do you have an actual use case?

Comment: @paulsm4 There are reasonable reasons to wonder this. Perhaps you want to understand how it works (it's reasonable to think that `new int` is perhaps equivalent to `new int[1]`), or perhaps you don't want to keep track of the details of how something was allocated. That's even more true in your `malloc`/`delete` example; if you interface with a C library you might actually have a hard time keeping track of which pointers came from where.

Comment: @paulsm4 I think the use case is: "I don't want to check how I allocated that object, whether with `new` or with `new []`, and I would like to have a universal `delete` that I can use in all situations"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it won't be. Deleting something with `delete []` that was not allocated with `new []` produces undefined behaviour. And why  would you want to? You allocated the memory, so you should know how to delete it. For further information, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete.

Comment: @wally see the cppreference page I added a link to.

Comment: It is safe to `delete[]` every pointer, as long as every pointer is allocated with `new[]`.  Even if it is `new foo[1]`.  Otherwise, no...  it would crash the program on my machine.

Comment: (Because my environment has separate heaps for `new` and `new[]` and `malloc`.)

Comment: @wally [\[expr.delete\]p2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.delete#2)

Comment: Actually, the statement isn’t entirely true: the `new` expression doesn’t need to mention `[]` to make `delete[]` necessary: `using array = int[10]; int* a = new array;`.

Comment: @Dietmar But isn't that array still allocated with `new[]`?

Comment: @NeilButterworth It's allocated with an [*array new-expression*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.new#5), but syntactically it there are no square brackets in the vicinity of the keyword `new`, so it might be confusing.

Comment: Clearly not: there are no brackets in the *new expression*. Internally it will call `operator new[]()`, of course. However, the rule in the standard talks about *array objects* and not the syntax actually used.

Comment: Tricky!  That is a good point!

Comment: @Eljay Huh. I didn't know of any platforms that in practice didn't use `malloc` for `operator new`. I wouldn't expect `delete` and `delete[]` to be interchangeable in practice on any platform, because `delete[]` needs access to extra information `new` isn't allowed to store.

Comment: I'd reword the end of that last comment as "`new` isn't required to store." The implementation could store the book-keeping in cherry blossoms so long as it conforms to the standard. And yes, I would LOVE to see that computer.